# Is there somewhere to complain about offensive moderator behaviour?

Tags: support, moderators

Is there anywhere or anyone to complain to about the behaviour of moderators? I've been "spoken" to offensively by a moderator, and I'm unhappy about it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's **right here**. You already found it!

Alternatively, if it's a sensitive issue that you'd prefer not be discussed out in the open, you can email `team@stackoverflow.com` about it, citing all relevant details, and someone will contact you in private. The advantage of that versus raising another moderator flag is that it's guaranteed to be handled by one of the Stack Overflow employees, rather than a community-elected moderator.

But please remember: moderators are people, too. They sometimes make mistakes and/or have temporary lapses in judgement. Just because they were harsh with you once or made a decision that you disagree with doesn't mean that they're bad moderators, that they'll hold a grudge against you, or even that they'll make the same decision a second time.

Comment: In fact, we can't even be guaranteed to make the same decision the _first_ time thanks to our super spiffy quantum moderator tools.

Comment: I think this is a good rule to live by in life generally, online, as well as offline: no matter how perfect a person seems or pretends to be, never forget that human beings are ***flawed***. Even the "perfect" ones. Given that, it's important to forgive sometimes, too. Sometimes, you just have to let things slide, especially the little ones (in the "grande scheme of things" sort of way).

Comment: They do not respond to emails.

Comment: They *absolutely* respond to emails, assuming that you've sent them an email worth responding to. If you start out being confrontational and insulting, I imagine you are less likely to get a response.

Comment: "Right here" made sense a very long time ago, but nowadays you'd want to post on the per-site meta of the relevant site. Meta Stack Exchange is rarely the right place to post, since many questions require domain knowledge or privileges only held by members of the relevant site.

Comment: Note that this answer was posted when this site was the Meta site specifically for Stack Overflow. There was no such thing as a network-wide Meta Stack Exchange. As Laurel says, the advice would be different today.

Answer (score 6):

Right here! If it's something you prefer not to be made public, you can always email team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Are there similar email addresses for other forums of stack exchange?